# Юнити проект, создаю скрипт, а он выдает ошибку при открытии

Tags: c#, unity3d

Просто есть проект на юнити, пробуем создать скрипт, открываем, а он выдает такую ошибку, с чем может быть связано?

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Ссылкой не пробовали пользоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, у вас неправильно установлена Visual Studiо. Попробуйте переустановить. При установке Unity, например из UnityHub есть опция для установки Visual Studio Community версии.